# Code works fine when print statement is present, but throws error when I comment the print

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having really strange error. I am using Python 2.7 on Linux Mint OS. Here is the code:

```
with open(edgeClusteringPath) as f:
    for line in f:
        clustId = str(currCluster)
        spl = line.split(" ")
        # print spl
        for i in spl:
            # print i
            (first, second) = edgeNodes[int(float(i))]
            nodeClusters.setdefault(first, set())
            nodeClusters.setdefault(second, set())
            nodeClusters[first].add(clustId)
            nodeClusters[second].add(clustId)
            # print i

        currCluster += 1
```

edgeClusteringPath is a path to a space separated data and edgeNodes is a dictionary with key = edgeId and value = (firstNode, secondNode). The problem occurs in the second for loop. This code gives me error:

```
> line 34, in <module>
    (first, second) = edgeNodes[int(float(i))]
KeyError: 0
```

But when I uncomment one (or both) of the `print i` statements, the execution works fine (without error). It is really strange, I do not see how the print statement could affect the remaining code. I could uncomment the print statement, but I do not actually need that printing, so I would rather get rid of that line.

Here is a sample of edgNodes:

```
87388: (3250, 6041), 87389: (3250, 6045), 87390: (3250, 6046)
```

It is a huge dictionary, so I extracted only 3 key-value pairs.
Thank you in advance!

Edit:
Now my code works. I had problem with the paths I have been using. I used wrong file to initialize edgeNodes dictionary and it caused the problems. However, I posted the question just to see if anybody had idea how adding one line changes the behavior of the code. I have been using Java for 3 years and never had similar issue. I am new to Python and do not know how it works internally, so I wished to know if anybody has idea about the effect on one line of the other code.

Thank you for your opinions and suggestions!

Comment: The parentheses around first and second aren't familiar.  What happens if you change that to `first, second = edgeNodes[int(float(i))]`?

Comment: Can you show us the data for edgeNodes as well as for edgeClusteringPath ?

Comment: @wallyk I tried without the parentheses, still the same error

Comment: Why are you casting it to a float, then an int? Why not just int?

Comment: Does it specifically have to be that print statement, or can you replace it with another quasi-no-op like `i=i`?

Comment: @RobFoley, because `int("1.0")` will error

Comment: @gunner, how are you running the code?

Comment: @ chepner thanks for the idea, but it is still a hack :) I am wondering why the code does not work without any additional line

Comment: Please, show us the disassembled code. `import dis`, then embed the code in a function, say `test()`, then `dis.dis(test)`.

Comment: @gunner it wasn't just a hack – it's informative: Does it work with `pass` or `i=i` instead of `print`?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do something to modify `edgeNodes` in between trials?

Comment: @RobFoley I firstly parse into float, so I am doing `int(1.0)` , not `int("1.0")`. And it works fine.

Comment: I don't think this is the real code. Come up with a [complete minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @gunner, `print edgeNodes` at the very start of your code and add the output

Comment: What do your dict keys look like? Strings? Ints? (Probably the latter)

Comment: @RobFoley I cast it firstly to float because in the file I am reading from 100000 was written as 1e+05, so I had errors without the float cast.

Comment: I would be surprised if the error did not always happen. uncomment the print, run the code and outside both for loops add a `print("finished")` and see if you can see it, also from where are you running the code and does `print(0 in edgeNodes)` return True?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I added a sample of the dictionary edgeNodes

Comment: @gunner, do the two things above and add what it outputs

Comment: @PadraicCunningham in the meantime I solved the issue, I have mistake with one of the file paths I am using. `print(0 in edgeNodes)` printed False, so it was about the path, I had been using wrong data to initialize edgeNodes. I suspected before posting the question that I have such kind of error, but I posted it just to see if anybody has idea how adding of a line affects the rest of the code.

Comment: I am sure the error always happened, how and where from you are running the code would be interesting as it is effecting how the error traceback is propagated, this is almost certainly not a python issue.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, the error always happened. Now my code is working. It was my mistake, but it was strange. The compiler does not execute the lines where the error occurs when there is some additional meaningless statement, such as i = i, and it tries to execute them and gives and error when there is no additional statement. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No worries, I think you will find the code goes no further than the line that causes the keyError print or no print. Where were you running the script from?